# I have a WiFi connection, but it won't show up in GUI

Tags: drivers, wireless, mac

I installed Ubuntu server on a 2011 iMac and set up the WiFi when promoted. After setup I decided to add a GUI by running

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

when I rebooted I installed Firefox and Chrome and ran a google search and they both of them worked. In settings, it says

> no wifi adapter found

but when I run `lspci | grep -i network`, it shows a detected WiFi controller.

Comment: It is probably being controlled in netplan. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: it says this when I run "cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml"
"cat: /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml: Permission denied
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2"

Comment: no that post does not anwser my question because I have a wifi connection but it wont show up in the gooey

Comment: What does this command result with in terminal `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net`

Comment: here are the results of that 02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4] (rev 10)
 Subsystem: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM57765 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:16b4]
 Kernel driver in use: tg3
 Kernel modules: tg3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR93xx Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0030] (rev 01)
 Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:009a]
 Kernel driver in use: ath9k
 Kernel modules: ath9k

Comment: See the link posted by waltinator, run the wireless script, then upload results to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL as that wifi has been supported for quite a while

Comment: where can i find the link

Comment: If you ran the commands, see if you get a link in terminal after`cat wireless-info.txt|nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: it says no such file or directory also I am currently using the computer to do these responses

Comment: Run in terminal `wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info && cat wireless-info.txt | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: here are the results of that https://termbin.com/548f

Comment: URL for `sudo cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml| nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: now what do I do

Comment: Since you are using netplan to define the wifi connection it is not available to Network Manager.

Comment: please explain that in more simple terms I am new to networking.Is there anything I can do about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you back up your current netplan file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.yaml  /etc/netplan/00-installer-config-wifi.bak
```

Write a new one:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about spacing, indentation, etc., so proofread carefully twice.

Save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and exit (Ctrl+x).

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
sudo sudo service NetworkManager restart
```

Is there any improvement? It might take a reboot.

Comment: how do I know if it backed up and what do I do if I does not work

Comment: Do you see the backup in `ls /etc/netplan`? If it doesn't work, you run and post the wireless script again and we troubleshoot.

Comment: thank you that worked